# How I can fix this error? terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, qt

This is the code:
Function :

```
QString printDir2(QString path, int level)
{
int check =1;
QDir folder(path);

QString space;
QString buffer;
qDebug() <<"nivelul 1 \n";
for(int i=0; 1<level; i++)
    space +="    ";
qDebug() <<"nivelul 2 \n";
foreach(QFileInfo temp , folder.entryInfoList())
{
    if(check > 2)
    {
        qDebug() <<"nivelul 4 \n";
        buffer += space + temp.absoluteFilePath() + "\n";
        if(temp.isDir())
            buffer += printDir2(temp.absoluteFilePath(), ++level);
    }
    check++;
    qDebug() <<"nivelul 3 \n";
}
return buffer;
```

}

and here i call the function:

```
QString drum="/home/sunny/Desktop/QT/descarca";
        str=printDir2(drum,0);
        qDebug()<<str<<"acesta este drumul";
```

How to fix this erorr from terminal:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'   what():  std::bad_alloc
this is the terminal when i run ths code: http://s013.radikal.ru/i325/1501/e5/aade9346f0aa.png

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` is thrown when there isn't enough available memory.  You can fix the problem by either getting a computer with more memory or changing your program so it requires less memory.

Comment: I have enough memory, i try to make a debug and see that after 4th recursion he throw this error! I think that the error is in the method how I call the function.

Comment: Where exactly (what line) was the exception thrown from?

Comment: You may have enough memory. But if your application is 32bit, you have a limit in allocating.

Answer (score 1):

You may have run into infinite recursion.

Run your program in the debugger. If you use gdb, you can issue the command `catch throw` before `run`. Then the debugger will stop when the exception is thrown. You may have to move `up` a few times to see which line in your code threw the exception.